# Vue3 can't assign parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I want to make a function, where I am giving in 2 parameters, string, and array, and that array is equal to what I get from Axios, but I run into the problem {'assignment' is assigned a value but never used.}, but I want that the this.quizzAllCategories is equal to parameter assignment

```js
callAPI(params: string, assignment: quizzType[]) {
      axios
        .get(`https://printful.com/test-quiz.php?action=${params}`)
        .then((res) => {
          assignment = res.data;
        });
    },
  },
  async created() {
    await this.callAPI("quizzes", this.quizzAllCategories);
  },
```

Comment: ehm do you know the difference between parameters and return values of functions?

Comment: Parameters are what are we giving in to the function, but the return value is what we get when the function is done

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the data from the function, not expect the "return variable" as another parameter, that's not how it works.

```
callAPI(params: string) {
  return axios
    .get(`https://printful.com/test-quiz.php?action=${params}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    });
  },
},
async created() {
  this.quizzAllCategories = await this.callAPI("quizzes");
},
```

Answer (score -2):

ESLint lint behavior is right. You've declared assignment and assigned it a value, but u aren't using it in your Code anywhere.

**Solution:** It should disappear if use it anywhere:)

**Solution 2 which is not recommended:** you can disable it by adding these, before this line

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

assignment = res.data

/* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
```

Comment: Yes I agree, my question is, how can I write that res.data is equal to what I gave in the second parameter, how can I assign whatever the second parameter is to res.data

Comment: can you please let us know why you want to assign that res.data to assignment? Because you want to use it further right? Because u already assigned it through this line of code but if you do not wanna use it then what is the use of assigning it? If you want to use it then use it and you will have no warnings after that.
Just type return assignment; after that assignment = res.data line.

Comment: I want to make a function that I can use multiple times so I don't have 4 long Axios calls but I have only one.  to which I pass params = changing part of Axios, and then assignment to which res.data is saved in, sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: Just type return assignment; after that assignment = res.data line.

Rest of your code has no issues.

Comment: Overwriting the passed in value (Note: value, not reference) won't have any effect and will most certainly not have the desired effect.